# Hover over something for information to appear in another

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to find ways to to hover over something so that more information will appear in a different section. I have been looking at similar questions that were posted but I am still not sure how to do it.

I want "Recently on Sale" to show up first, then as I hover over the others, more information will appear for them respectively. Here is the link to what I have been working on: http://jsfiddle.net/saikirakiva/jVaLd/

I have been using just css, is javascript more suitable for what I am trying to do?

Thank you!

Comment: would be a lot easier to do with js

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is useful because it allows you to delay hiding the second element when the mouse moves away from the first element. This feature is especially important in nested drop down menus, because users frequently leave a menu item for a short time while navigating to its submenu.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/Vhg6p/9/

Comment: I tried to do what you did but for some reasons, the text didn't change as you hover over them. Also, I am planning to add images to the box that appear as I hover over. What I am trying to do is similar to how http://www.quibids.com/ did for its main page.

Comment: Is it possible to remove 'title' and replace it with 'id' so that I can link more content. Thank you!